# Refreshing my ListView everytime i got a new SMS

Tags: android, listview, sms

I realized,there're some questions here, but i think my code is really different from them (i'm a beginner) and i can't understand their answers!

So i want to refresh my ListView everytime i receive a SMS, i tried to use `cursor.requery();` and some methods which i found on google but it's still not working.

This is my code  :

```
public class SMSActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<String>();
// String ADDRESS[];
// int total = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null,
            null, null);

    int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");

    if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst())
        return;

    smsList.clear();
    do {
        String str = "Sender : " + cursor.getString(indexAddr) + "\n"
                + cursor.getString(indexBody);
        smsList.add(str);
        // ADDRESS[total] = cursor.getString(indexAddr);
        // total++;
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    ListView lvSms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
    lvSms.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList));

    // cursor.requery();
    lvSms.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

EDITED :
And this is the Class where i extends it with BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIF_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            str += "You Get New SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";

        Toast.makeText(arg0, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String tickerText = str;

        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        String contentTitle = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        String contentText = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, SMSReply.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, intent, 0);

        notif.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, contentTitle, contentText, pi);
        notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notif);

        String tempSMS = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        Intent pass = new Intent();
        Bundle bundlePass = new Bundle();

        bundlePass.putString("key", tempSMS);
        pass.putExtras(bundlePass);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to link those two Class so everytime the BroadcastReceiver works(new SMS come) my ListView will be updated(just like the SMS app in your phone)

Thanks All.

Comment: You told the list should be updated whenever the SMS is received. where is your Braodcast Receiver?

Comment: Err..i have it in another Class...i will update my question, thanks Sir :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define adapter as global public variable,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

inside `onCreate()` assign it,

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList));
```

in your `BroadcastReceiver` access the `smsList` and add to it the new sms,

then access your adapter this way,

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this function will notify the adapter that smsList values have been changed and will update the list.

Comment: Thanks Sir :D
But i have a problem, i don't understand how to do this sentence "in your BroadcastReceiver access the smsList and add to it the new sms,

then access your adapter this way" This is the source of my problem, i already think to link my list but i don't know how to do it.
Thanks Sir :D

Comment: Btw, is it okay to have 2 adapter Sir?i have made my own in the last sentence in my SMSActivity Class and i create your adapter, so there's 2 adapters in my SMSActivity Class.
I mean, could they be synchronized?
Thanks Sir :D

Comment: I meant whenever you receive an sms (onReceive) you have to update the smsList array with the new sms (add() function) then notify the adapter that smsList have been changed, about 2 adapters, I believe not, I prefer to implment the function onReceive inside your activity class

Comment: to implment the broadcast inside your activity, use same as what tiago posted but declare as global variable 'BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcasReceiver() { @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) { //write here } };'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BroadcastReceiver class with an abstract method, like this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        ...
        do your stuff here
        ...

        myAbsMethod(newSms);
    }
    public abstract void myAbsMethod(String sms);
}
```

Then, in your activity you do something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private final MyReceiver myReceiver;
    private ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ...

    public MyActivity() {
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void myAbsMethod(String sms) {
                smsList.add(sms);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        IntentFilter filterState = new IntentFilter(YOUR_SMS_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filterState)
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ...
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
}
```

So, basically, you're registering this receiver inside your activity class, then whenever you receive this broadcast, your activity will listen, and you can do whatever you want in this overridden abstract method.

Comment: Is it possible? bcoz when I declare abstract method in my brodcast receiver class it say's class should be abstract and If I made class abstract then in my activity I am not able to instatiate my bordcast reveiver as abstract classes can not be instatiate.?